# swift - change label in header when UI Switch changes in the Navigation Bar

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to change the label in my header to correlate with my `UISwitch`
though I have have no success as yet?

`setLeftNavButton()` is called in `viewDidLoad()`

```
func setLeftNavButton() {

    let switchControl=UISwitch()

    //switchControl.isOn = true
    //switchControl.setOn(true, animated: false)
    switchControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchValueDidChange), for: .valueChanged)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: switchControl)

   self.switchControl = switchControl

}

var switchControl: UISwitch?

func switchValueDidChange(){

    guard  let mySwitch = switchControl else { return }

    if mySwitch.isOn {

        header?.onlineOfflineStatusLabel.text = "on"
    }
    else {
        header?.onlineOfflineStatusLabel.text = "off"

    }

    self.header?.reloadInputViews()
    self.collectionView?.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: Hey what is self.header ?

Comment: the UICollectionViewCell that sits at the top of the UICollectionViewController that holds the label

Comment: Can you provide entire code of this View Controller?

Comment: i can't its too long , i just really need to know how to set a uilabel's text to "on" and "off" when a UI switch changes to on and off , done programatically with out storyboards?

Comment: and the switch is in the nav bar , and the label is in a collection view cell that sits at the top of the ui collection view controller?

Comment: I would use the `UISwitch` value in the `cellForItemAt` to update my cell text value and just reloadData on switch change

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
func setLeftNavButton() {

        let switchControl = UISwitch()
        switchControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchValueDidChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: switchControl)

        self.switchControl = switchControl

 }

 @objc
 func switchValueDidChange(_ sender: UISwitch){

        if sender.isOn {
            header?.onlineOfflineStatusLabel.text = "on"
        } else {
            header?.onlineOfflineStatusLabel.text = "off"
        }

        self.header?.reloadInputViews()
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()

}
```